# Kubuntu 17.04 on VM: loopback interface routed "outside"

Tags: linux-networking, loopback

Disclaimer: Yes, I know my problem description might be not very accurate and my terminology as well. Can not change that since I am new to this topic and do not know it yet. But I apprechiate suggestions how to improve my question.

My problem: I have a fresh Kubuntu 17.04 installation (on a VM) where I had trouble to get LAN/Internet running so I was trying stuff here and there until I figured out.

Now it works (DNS, routing through gateway, DHCP, etc).

Strange thing is, that the loopback device wants to go "outside of my machine" (what is the propper terminology here?). I see this for example if I enter "127.0.0.1" in the browser it is not Apache showing the default page, but our proxy is blocking and giving a message.

I have no clue if this might be my problem and to diagnose the "initial problem" and to fix this then...

Comment: You've given no information at all about what you've configured and how you configured it, neither on the OS side or the hypervisor side.

Comment: Use `http://127.0.0.1` instead `127.0.0.1`